# CSS keyframe -- start from dynamic height

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

I have a bunch of list items. I want each to vertically expand when I click on it, like an accordion. To do so nicely, I'm using keyframes, like so:

```css
@keyframe expand {
      0% { height: 100px; }
    100% { height: 200px; }
}
```

The only problem is, these list items are dynamic in height, as they contain other elements. Is there any way to set a dynamic starting height for the keyframe? The way it works is, if it's bigger than `100px` to begin with, it shrinks and then grows.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to dynamically create '@-Keyframe' CSS animations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18481550/how-to-dynamically-create-keyframe-css-animations)

Comment: Best way to do this would be to put a transition on your div and then manipulate the height css via javascript

Comment: The height at `0%` is the original height of that element, right?

Comment: The problem is that height: auto; --> height: 200px; won't work. So use  max-height instead. Code is like @keyframe expand {
      0% { max-height: 0; }
    100% { max-height: 200px; }
}

Comment: @chipChocolate.py Yes, at 0% it is the original height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the list items a `max-height` and then use [`transition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition) to get to a `min-height` when clicked. Use `overflow: hidden` on the list items to contain items that would push the list item past 100px.

### Working Example

In this example, all list items expand on click. Obviously, you would change the javascript to just expand the list item that was clicked.

```js
var expand = document.getElementById("items");

expand.addEventListener('click', function() {
  this.classList.toggle('click');
}, false);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
ul {
  background: #FF0;
  padding: 1px 0;
}
li {
  background: #F00;
  margin: 10px;
  transition: all 1s;
  max-height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.click li {
  min-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<ul id="items">
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Larger
    <br />Item</li>
  <li>Largest
    <br />Item
    <br />In
    <br />this
    <br />List</li>
</ul>
```