# How to update values from @keyframes with angularJS?

Tags: angularjs, css, keyframe

I'm loading different pictures with AngularJS and I have the following keyframes:

```
@keyframes backgroundMoving {
    from {
        background-position: 0 0;
    }
    to {
        background-position: 638px 500px;
    }
}
```

It's used by:

```
.moving-bg {
    -webkit-animation: backgroundMoving 0s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: backgroundMoving 0s linear infinite;
    -o-animation: backgroundMoving 0s linear infinite;
    animation: backgroundMoving 0s linear infinite;
}
```

I'd like to update the background-position (i. e. 638px 500px) dynamically based on the image selected with angular. The images can be any size since they are uploaded by the user.

Is it possible to performed this in an angular controller? I used to play with `ng-class` and `ng-style` but I have no idea how to manage @keyframes.

Comment: Check this [how-to-dynamically-create-keyframe-css-animations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18481550/how-to-dynamically-create-keyframe-css-animations)