# Pass random value in HTML-Style

Tags: javascript, html, random, styles

I need to pass a random number in a HTMl Style that is attached to a figure which rotates. I am unable to do so even after trying hard. Following is the code which I wrote but no effect.

```
 <script>
    @ViewBag.angle  = ( Math.floor(Math.random()* (5 - 1)+1))+deg;
 </script
 <style>
   keyframes service-level{100%{transform:rotateZ(@ViewBag.angle);}}    
 </style>
```

If I use below code with static value it works fine. Please advise.

```
 keyframes service-level{100%{transform:rotateZ(90deg);}}
```

Comment: hi, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18481550/how-to-dynamically-create-keyframe-css-animations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you're using some templating language which replaces `@`–keywords with values, the browser (or CSS parser) has no idea what to do with `@ViewBag.angle`.

You would need to inject the style via javascript:

```
var style = document.createElement("style");
var angle = (Math.floor(Math.random() * (5 - 1) + 1)) + "deg";
style.type = "text/css";
style.innerHTML = "@keyframes service-level {100% {transform: rotate(" + angle + ");}}";
document.head.appendChild(style);
```

And use the animation name in CSS (linked .css file or inline, doesn't matter here):

```
div {
  animation-name: service-level;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

[Codepen example here](http://codepen.io/helb/pen/YZXjqY)

If you want to have **many randomly rotated elements**, `transition` would be a better fit:

```
[].forEach.call(divs, function(div) {
    var angle = (Math.floor(Math.random() * (5 - 1) + 1)) + "deg";
    div.style.transform = "rotate(" + angle + ")";
});
```

CSS:

```
div {
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transition: all 3s;
}
```

[Codepen example here](http://codepen.io/helb/pen/RpPBQY)