# ng-style not working with stroke-dasharray and stroke-dashoffset CSS elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, css-animations

Passing these values through ng-style, so:

```
ng-style="{'stroke-dasharray':data.value, 'stroke-dashoffset': data.value}"
```

breaks my donut chart, but if they are in the CSS in the class applied to the div element (circle_animation, please see in Fiddle). Here the fiddle:

[Donut chart](https://jsfiddle.net/MrFabio80/fbo2x5hr/1/)

Any idea? The goal is to have ng-style working, so to pass the circumference dynamically...

Fabio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ng-style normally expects an expression which evaluates to an object with key-value pair. It won't perform interpolation within a string as you've used.The way you're using is how `ng-class` works.

To make it work, you need to do something like below:

```
<circle id="circle" class="circle_animation" r="69.85699" cy="81" cx="81" stroke-width="8" stroke="#6fdb6f" fill="none" ng-style="{'stroke-dasharray': {{data.value}}, 'stroke-dashoffset': {{data.value}}}"/>
```

See working example: [Plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/s75ZkjQh5Dz7jHF9NKnp?p=preview)

Comment: Hi Narain! Thanks a lot, I have one more question: do you know also how to edit the value representing the percentage (stroke-dashoffset, 50)? It is in `@keyframes donut-chart-1 {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 50;
  }
}`

Comment: Well, I'm not sure about that one. Take a look at this if it helps -http://stackoverflow.com/a/18481715/572799