# Count Rows in a dynamic table

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a dynamically generated table which will have different numbers of rows at any given time.

```
<div class="marquee">
    <table runat="server" id="TableFeedReader">
    </table>
</div>
```

I want to count the number of rows with JQuery and pass the number as an integer to calculate a dynamic property similar to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31868716/7333610). This code gives me a zero for my dynamic value when the HTML is generated:

```
    $(function () {
        var rowCount = $('TableFeedReader').length;
        var newCount = parseInt(rowCount) * 2;
        var style = document.createElement('style');
        style.type = 'text/css';
        style.id = 'keyframe'
        var keyFrames = '\
@-webkit-keyframes marquee {\
    0% {\
        top:   9em\
    }\
    100% {\
        top:   -A_DYNAMIC_VALUEem\
    }\
}\
@-moz-keyframes marquee {\
    0% {\
        top:   9em\
    }\
    100% {\
        top:   -A_DYNAMIC_VALUEem\
    }\
}';
        style.innerHTML = keyFrames.replace(/A_DYNAMIC_VALUE/g, newCount);
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);
    });
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: The number of rows in a table is given by its [*rows*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/rows) property. Once you have a reference to the table, then *tableRef.rows* is the count of rows. It's also live, so once you have a reference to the *rows* object, you can check it to see how many rows there are at any time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `var rowCount = $('TableFeedReader').length;` to `var rowCount = $('#TableFeedReader tr').length;`

```js
console.log($('#TableFeedReader tr').length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table runat="server" id="TableFeedReader">
  <tr><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td></td></tr>
  <tr><td></td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks. It seems like it should work, but it's not working on my end. I keep getting a zero. I think I'll take a break and get back to it later.

Comment: @TomBB can you give us a working demo that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Make sure the code runs after the table is populated.

Comment: So.... A <tbody> is inserted when the table is dynamically generated. Who knew :). That's why I kept getting a zero. I probably should have looked at the html output first - lesson learned.  '$("#TableFeedReader >tbody >tr").length;' is what I should have been using. Thanks to everyone on this thread who chimed in.

Answer (score 0):

`$` takes a CSS selector, not an ID. You might have meant `$('#TableFeedReader')`, but that still doesn't make too much sense, because there's usually only one element with a given ID on the page.

I'd try `$('#TableFeedReader tr')`.

Comment: Selectors are used for CSS, but they are [*specified separately*](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/) and are used for other purposes, so just "selector". ;-)