# Make an analogue clock that corresponds with local time using javascript

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

I created an analogue clock that works fine with css. 
Right here

```css
.frame {
 position : absolute;
 top : 0;
 bottom : 0;
 right : 0;
 left : 0;
 margin : auto;
 width : 100%;
 height : 100%;
 border-radius : 50%;
 border : 5px groove #000;
 border-color : ;
 /* transform : rotateZ(45deg); */
 box-shadow : inset 0 0 10px 2px #000;
}
.secHand, .minHand, .hourHand {
 background :  ;
 position : absolute ;
 top :  2%;
 bottom : ;
 width : 0;
 right : 0;
 left : 0;
 margin : auto;
 transform-origin : 100% 100%;
 /* transform : rotate(-45deg); */
 border-right : 1px solid #000;
 }
 .hourCut, .miniCut {
  position : absolute ;
  width : 100% ;
  bottom : 0;
 }
 .hourCut {
  height : 50% ;
  border-right : 3px solid #000;
 }
 .miniCut {
  height : 70% ;
  border-right : 2px solid #00f;
  }
 .hourHand {
  height : 48%;
  background : transparent ;
  border-right : 3px solid transparent;
  animation : clockwise 43200s linear infinite;
  z-index : 5 ;
 }
 .minHand {
  height : 48%;
  border-right : 2px solid transparent;
  animation : clockwise 3600s linear infinite;
  z-index : 4 ;
 }

 .secHand {
  height : 48%;
 animation : clockwise 60s linear infinite ;
 z-index : 6 ;
}
@keyframes clockwise {
 0% {
  transform : rotateZ(0deg);
}
100% {
transform : rotateZ(360deg);
}
}
.containerX {
 position : absolute;
 top : 0 ;
 bottom : 0 ;
 left : 0;
 right : 0;
 margin : auto;
 height : 300px;
 width : 300px;
}
.innerFrame, .smallFrame {
 position : absolute ;
 top : 0 ;
 bottom : 0 ;
 right : 0 ;
 left : 0 ;
 margin : auto ;
 border : 1px solid transparent;
 border-radius : 50% ;
 background : #fff;
 display : ; 
}
.innerFrame {
 height : 90% ;
 width : 90% ;
 box-shadow : 0 0 10px 2px #000;
 z-index : 1 ;
}
.smallFrame {
 height : 80% ;
 width : 80% ;
 z-index : 3 ;
}
.calibrate {
 position : absolute ;
 top : 0 ;
 bottom : ;
 right : 0 ;
 left : 0 ;
 margin : auto ;
 height : 50% ;
 width : 0 ;
 transform-origin : 100% 100% ;
 border-right : 1px solid #fff;
}
.indicators {
 border-right : 1px solid #00f;
 box-shadow : 0 0 5px 0px #000;
 z-index : 2  ;
}
.knob {
 position : absolute ;
 top : 0 ;
 bottom : 0 ;
 right : 0 ;
 left : 0 ;
 margin : auto ;
 height : 1.5% ;
 width : 1.5% ;
 border-radius : 50% ;
 border : 3px solid #000;
 background : #fff ;
 z-index : 7 ;
}
.r0 {
 transform : rotateZ(0deg)
}
.r6 {
 transform : rotateZ(6deg) 
}
.r12 {
 transform : rotateZ(12deg)
}
.r18 {
 transform : rotateZ(18deg)
}
.r24 {
 transform : rotateZ(24deg)
}
.r30 {
 transform : rotateZ(30deg)
}
.r36 {
 transform : rotateZ(36deg)
}
.r42 {
 transform : rotateZ(42deg)
}
.r48 {
 transform : rotateZ(48deg)
}
.r54 {
 transform : rotateZ(54deg)
}
.r60 {
 transform : rotateZ(60deg)
}
.r66 {
 transform : rotateZ(66deg)
}
.r72 {
 transform : rotateZ(72deg)
}
.r78 {
 transform : rotateZ(78deg)
}
.r84 {
 transform : rotateZ(84deg)
}
.r90 {
 transform : rotateZ(90deg)
}
.r96 {
 transform : rotateZ(96deg)
}
.r102 {
 transform : rotateZ(102deg)
}
.r108 {
 transform : rotateZ(108deg)
}
.r114 {
 transform : rotateZ(114deg)
}
.r120 {
 transform : rotateZ(120deg)
}
.r126 {
 transform : rotateZ(126deg)
}
.r132 {
 transform : rotateZ(132deg)
}
.r138 {
 transform : rotateZ(138deg)
}
.r144 {
 transform : rotateZ(144deg)
}
.r150 {
 transform : rotateZ(150deg)
}
.r156 {
 transform : rotateZ(156deg)
}
.r162 {
 transform : rotateZ(162deg)
}
.r168 {
 transform : rotateZ(168deg)
}
.r174 {
 transform : rotateZ(174deg)
}
.r180 {
 transform : rotateZ(180deg)
}
.r186 {
 transform : rotateZ(186deg)
}
.r192 {
 transform : rotateZ(192deg)
}
.r198 {
 transform : rotateZ(198deg)
}
.r204 {
 transform : rotateZ(204deg)
}
.r210 {
 transform : rotateZ(210deg)
}
.r216 {
 transform : rotateZ(216deg)
}
.r222 {
 transform : rotateZ(222deg)
}
.r228 {
 transform : rotateZ(228deg)
}
.r234 {
 transform : rotateZ(234deg)
}
.r240 {
 transform : rotateZ(240deg)
}
.r246 {
 transform : rotateZ(246deg)
}
.r252 {
 transform : rotateZ(252deg)
}
.r258 {
 transform : rotateZ(258deg)
}
.r264 {
 transform : rotateZ(264deg)
}
.r270 {
 transform : rotateZ(270deg)
}
.r276 {
 transform : rotateZ(276deg)
}
.r282 {
 transform : rotateZ(282deg)
}
.r288 {
 transform : rotateZ(288deg)
}
.r294 {
 transform : rotateZ(294deg)
}
.r300 {
 transform : rotateZ(300deg)
}
.r306 {
 transform : rotateZ(306deg)
}
.r312 {
 transform : rotateZ(312deg)
}
.r318 {
 transform : rotateZ(318deg)
}
.r324 {
 transform : rotateZ(324deg)
}
.r330 {
 transform : rotateZ(330deg)
}
.r336 {
 transform : rotateZ(336deg)
}
.r342 {
 transform : rotateZ(342deg)
}
.r348 {
 transform : rotateZ(348deg)
}
.r354 {
 transform : rotateZ(354deg)
}
.r358 {
 transform : rotateZ(360deg)
}
```

```html
<div class="containerX">
        <div class="frame">
        <div class="secHand"></div>
        
        <div class="minHand">
            <div class="miniCut"></div>
            </div>
            
        <div class="hourHand">
            <div class="hourCut"></div>
            </div>
            
<div class="innerFrame"></div> 
<div class="smallFrame"></div>          
<div class="knob"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r0 indicators"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r6"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r12"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r18"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r24"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r30 indicators"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r36"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r42"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r48"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r54"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r60 indicators"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r66"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r72"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r78"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r84"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r90 indicators"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r96"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r102"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r108"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r114"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r120 indicators"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r126"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r132"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r138"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r144"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r150 indicators"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r156"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r162"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r168"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r174"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r180 indicators"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r186"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r192"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r198"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r204"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r210 indicators"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r216"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r222"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r228"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r234"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r240 indicators"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r246"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r252"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r258"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r264"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r270 indicators"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r276"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r282"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r288"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r294"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r300 indicators"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r306"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r312"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r318"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r324"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r330 indicators"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r336"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r342"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r348"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r354"></div>


    </div>
</div>
```

Each time the code runs, it starts from top 00:00 time. 
My aim is to make the clock read the correct time every time the code runs.

Comment: Here's a link to the clock https://codepen.io/Possible_bj/pen/WJMWwm

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please include all code relevant to the question **in the question itself**. Don't make us go off site to find important information about your question. Codepen could go down, by under maintenance etc. Please take the [tour] and read the [help] to help you improve your questions.

Comment: Edit to put clock code in question. Commented out unused CSS transforms instead of misspelling the property name as "transfor". You can re-edit or revert if you want to..

Comment: alright, taken.

Answer (score 0):

you can get an array of the hours like this:

```
const now = new Date();

const time = now.toLocaleTimeString().split(" ")[0].split(":");
```

And transform the hands of the clock like this:

```
document.querySelector(".hourHand").style.transform = `rotate(${(360 / 12) * time[0]}deg)`;

document.querySelector(".minHand").style.transform = `rotate(${(360 / 60) * time[1]}deg)`;

document.querySelector(".secHand").style.transform = `rotate(${(360 / 60) * time[2]}deg)`;
```

Then I would think you would need to apply the animation via JavaScript or something.  Have a look here:

[How to dynamically create '@-Keyframe' CSS animations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18481550/how-to-dynamically-create-keyframe-css-animations?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Here's the last link from the accepted answer of the previous post, this looks like it will work to set the starting position and the animation:

https://github.com/Keyframes/jQuery.Keyframes

Comment: Noted. But I don't understand how I could transform the hands to correspond.

Comment: Something like this function setTime() {
 var now = new Date();
  var currentTime = new Array();
  currentTime[0] = now.getHours();
 currentTime[1] = now.getMinutes();
  currentTime[2] = now.getSeconds();
  var setTime = currentTime.join(" : ");
time.innerHTML = setTime;
}
setInterval("setTime()", 1000);

Comment: @Possible So you want the text output of the time like ```00:21:34``` to appear on the screen as the clock moves, starting from ```00:00:00```?

Comment: Not exactly, what I want to do is to make the rotation of the hands correspond with the present time. @Eric's answer does the job easily but transition has a little off touch.

Comment: @Possible Right, so the example I gave would set that up for you if you remove the animation.  The problem is then how to animate it which should be explained by the link.  The code in your comment updates the time like ```00:12:34``` so I guess I'm confused.  Did this solve the problem for you?

Comment: Yes the example would. The code in my comment displayed that time because that was your current time

Answer (score 0):

Your going to have to do the animation in JavaScript code.  I used jQuery also. This is a start:

```
$('.minHand').css('animation','none');
$('.hourHand').css('animation','none'); 
$('.secHand').css('animation','none');

setInterval(function(){ 
  var d = new Date(); // for now
$('.hourHand').css('transform', 'rotate(' + d.getHours() * (360 /12) +'deg)');
$('.minHand').css('transform', 'rotate(' + (d.getMinutes()/60)*360 + 'deg)');
$('.secHand').css('transform', 'rotate(' + (d.getSeconds()/60)*360 + 'deg)');
},1000);
```

Comment: He's not using jQuery as far as I can tell.

Comment: I am, I do understand the above code. It does the job but when I add transition to it, it gets to 59 and makes an anti-clockwise movement to 0.

Answer (score 0):

**Setting the clock in CSS stylesheet rules**

*Edited to allow setting the CSS clock from Javascript any number of times - the  original version initialized the clock once.*

The first step in this version is give the HTMLStyleELement an id value, say "clockCSS", to facilitate accessing the style sheet. Alternatively assign the id value to a LINK element with "rel=stylesheet" if using an external style sheet.

Next replace the "clockwise" keyframes at-rule with separate "secFrames", "minFrames" and "hourFrames" at-rules for seconds, minutes and hours respectively. Include the new keyframe rules in the style sheet. They can all default to rotate from 0 to 360 degrees.

CSS changes should look similar to

```
.hourHand {
    height : 48%;
    background : transparent ;
    border-right : 3px solid transparent;
    animation : hourFrames 43200s linear infinite;
    z-index : 5 ;
}
.minHand {
    height : 48%;
    border-right : 2px solid transparent;
    animation : minFrames 3600s linear infinite;
    z-index : 4 ;
}
.secHand {
    height : 48%;
    animation : secFrames 60s linear infinite ;
    z-index : 6 ;
}
@keyframes hourFrames {
    0%   { transform : rotateZ(0deg);}
    100% { transform : rotateZ(360deg);}
}
@keyframes minFrames {
    0%   { transform : rotateZ(0deg);}
    100% { transform : rotateZ(360deg);}
}
@keyframes secFrames {
    0%   { transform : rotateZ(0deg);}
    100% { transform : rotateZ(360deg);}
}
```

Now the transform values in the keyframe rules can be set in JavaScript:

```
// helper function to find a style sheet from its id value

function findSheetById( id) {  // LINK rel=stylesheet or STYLE element id.
     for( var i = 0; i < document.styleSheets.length; ++i) {
         var sheet = document.styleSheets[i];
         if( sheet.ownerNode.id == id) {
             return sheet;
         }
     }
}

// helper function to find a keyframes rule (rule type 7) by name

function findKeyFramesRule( ruleList, name) {
    for( var i = 0; i < ruleList.length; ++i) {
        var rule = ruleList[i];
        if( rule.type == 7 && rule.name == name)
             return rule;
    }
}

// clock setting code based on the stylesheet.

const clockSheetId = "clockCSS";

function setClockTransform( keyframesName, startDeg) {
    let clockSheet = findSheetById(clockSheetId);
    let atRule = findKeyFramesRule( clockSheet.cssRules, keyframesName);
    let stops = atRule.cssRules;
    stops[0].style.transform = "rotateZ(" + startDeg + "deg)";
    stops[1].style.transform = "rotateZ(" + (startDeg+360) + "deg)";
}

function setClock( hour, min, sec, msec) {
    // convert parameters to degrees
    msec = msec || 0;
    sec += msec/1000;
    min += sec / 60;
    hour = hour + min/60;
    sec = sec%60 * 6;
    min = min%60 * 6;
    hour = hour%12 * 30;
    setClockTransform( 'secFrames', sec);
    setClockTransform( 'minFrames', min);
    setClockTransform( 'hourFrames', hour);
}

// and test:

var now = new Date();
setClock( now.getHours(), now.getMinutes(), now.getSeconds())
```

Note this is simplistic in that it relies on the known structure of the style sheet. It checks out in the latest versions of FireFox and Chrome. However, while IE11 set the clock and ran it, other CSS issues marred presentation.

**Test code**

```js
"use strict";

// helper function to find a style sheet from its id value

function findSheetById( id) {  // LINK rel=stylesheet or STYLE element id.
     for( var i = 0; i < document.styleSheets.length; ++i) {
         var sheet = document.styleSheets[i];
         if( sheet.ownerNode.id == id) {
             return sheet;
         }
     }
}

// helper function to find a keyframes rule (rule type 7) by name

function findKeyFramesRule( ruleList, name) {
    for( var i = 0; i < ruleList.length; ++i) {
        var rule = ruleList[i];
        if( rule.type == 7 && rule.name == name)
             return rule;
    }
}

// clock setting code

const clockSheetId = "clockCSS";

function setClockTransform( keyframesName, startDeg) {
    let clockSheet = findSheetById(clockSheetId);
    let atRule = findKeyFramesRule( clockSheet.cssRules, keyframesName);
    let stops = atRule.cssRules;
    stops[0].style.transform = "rotateZ(" + startDeg + "deg)";
    stops[1].style.transform = "rotateZ(" + (startDeg+360) + "deg)";
}

function setClock( hour, min, sec, msec) {
    // convert parameters to degrees
    msec = msec || 0;
    sec += msec/1000;
    min += sec / 60;
    hour = hour + min/60;
    sec = sec%60 * 6;
    min = min%60 * 6;
    hour = hour%12 * 30;
    setClockTransform( 'secFrames', sec);
    setClockTransform( 'minFrames', min);
    setClockTransform( 'hourFrames', hour);
}

var now = new Date();
setClock( now.getHours(), now.getMinutes(), now.getSeconds())
```

```html
<style type="text/css" id="clockCSS">
.frame {
    position : absolute;
    top : 0;
    bottom : 0;
    right : 0;
    left : 0;
    margin : auto;
    width : 100%;
    height : 100%;
    border-radius : 50%;
    border : 5px groove #000;
    border-color : ;
    /* transform : rotateZ(45deg); */
    box-shadow : inset 0 0 10px 2px #000;
}
.secHand, .minHand, .hourHand {
    background :  ;
    position : absolute ;
    top :  2%;
    bottom : ;
    width : 0;
    right : 0;
    left : 0;
    margin : auto;
    transform-origin : 100% 100%;
    /* transform : rotate(-45deg); */
    border-right : 1px solid #000;
}
.hourCut, .miniCut {
    position : absolute ;
    width : 100% ;
    bottom : 0;
}
.hourCut {
    height : 50% ;
    border-right : 3px solid #000;
}
.miniCut {
    height : 70% ;
    border-right : 2px solid #00f;
}
.hourHand {
    height : 48%;
    background : transparent ;
    border-right : 3px solid transparent;
    animation : hourFrames 43200s linear infinite;
    z-index : 5 ;
}
.minHand {
    height : 48%;
    border-right : 2px solid transparent;
    animation : minFrames 3600s linear infinite;
    z-index : 4 ;
}
.secHand {
    height : 48%;
    animation : secFrames 60s linear infinite ;
    z-index : 6 ;
}
@keyframes hourFrames {
    0%   { transform : rotateZ(0deg);}
    100% { transform : rotateZ(360deg);}
}
@keyframes minFrames {
    0%   { transform : rotateZ(0deg);}
    100% { transform : rotateZ(360deg);}
}
@keyframes secFrames {
    0%   { transform : rotateZ(0deg);}
    100% { transform : rotateZ(360deg);}
}

.containerX {
    position : absolute;
    top : 0 ;
    bottom : 0 ;
    left : 0;
    right : 0;
    margin : auto;
    height : 300px;
    width : 300px;
}
.innerFrame, .smallFrame {
    position : absolute ;
    top : 0 ;
    bottom : 0 ;
    right : 0 ;
    left : 0 ;
    margin : auto ;
    border : 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius : 50% ;
    background : #fff;
    display : ; 
}
.innerFrame {
    height : 90% ;
    width : 90% ;
    box-shadow : 0 0 10px 2px #000;
    z-index : 1 ;
}
.smallFrame {
    height : 80% ;
    width : 80% ;
    z-index : 3 ;
}
.calibrate {
    position : absolute ;
    top : 0 ;
    bottom : ;
    right : 0 ;
    left : 0 ;
    margin : auto ;
    height : 50% ;
    width : 0 ;
    transform-origin : 100% 100% ;
    border-right : 1px solid #fff;
}
.indicators {
    border-right : 1px solid #00f;
    box-shadow : 0 0 5px 0px #000;
    z-index : 2  ;
}
.knob {
    position : absolute ;
    top : 0 ;
    bottom : 0 ;
    right : 0 ;
    left : 0 ;
    margin : auto ;
    height : 1.5% ;
    width : 1.5% ;
    border-radius : 50% ;
    border : 3px solid #000;
    background : #fff ;
    z-index : 7 ;
}
.r0 {    transform : rotateZ(0deg)}
.r6 {    transform : rotateZ(6deg)}
.r12 {    transform : rotateZ(12deg)}
.r18 {    transform : rotateZ(18deg)}
.r24 {    transform : rotateZ(24deg)}
.r30 {    transform : rotateZ(30deg)}
.r36 {    transform : rotateZ(36deg)}
.r42 {    transform : rotateZ(42deg)}
.r48 {    transform : rotateZ(48deg)}
.r54 {    transform : rotateZ(54deg)}
.r60 {    transform : rotateZ(60deg)}
.r66 {    transform : rotateZ(66deg)}
.r72 {    transform : rotateZ(72deg)}
.r78 {    transform : rotateZ(78deg)}
.r84 {    transform : rotateZ(84deg)}
.r90 {    transform : rotateZ(90deg)}
.r96 {    transform : rotateZ(96deg)}
.r102 {    transform : rotateZ(102deg)}
.r108 {    transform : rotateZ(108deg)}
.r114 {    transform : rotateZ(114deg)}
.r120 {    transform : rotateZ(120deg)}
.r126 {    transform : rotateZ(126deg)}
.r132 {    transform : rotateZ(132deg)}
.r138 {    transform : rotateZ(138deg)}
.r144 {    transform : rotateZ(144deg)}
.r150 {    transform : rotateZ(150deg)}
.r156 {    transform : rotateZ(156deg)}
.r162 {    transform : rotateZ(162deg)}
.r168 {    transform : rotateZ(168deg)}
.r174 {    transform : rotateZ(174deg)}
.r180 {    transform : rotateZ(180deg)}
.r186 {    transform : rotateZ(186deg)}
.r192 {    transform : rotateZ(192deg)}
.r198 {    transform : rotateZ(198deg)}
.r204 {    transform : rotateZ(204deg)}
.r210 {    transform : rotateZ(210deg)}
.r216 {    transform : rotateZ(216deg)}
.r222 {    transform : rotateZ(222deg)}
.r228 {    transform : rotateZ(228deg)}
.r234 {    transform : rotateZ(234deg)}
.r240 {    transform : rotateZ(240deg)}
.r246 {    transform : rotateZ(246deg)}
.r252 {    transform : rotateZ(252deg)}
.r258 {    transform : rotateZ(258deg)}
.r264 {    transform : rotateZ(264deg)}
.r270 {    transform : rotateZ(270deg)}
.r276 {    transform : rotateZ(276deg)}
.r282 {    transform : rotateZ(282deg)}
.r288 {    transform : rotateZ(288deg)}
.r294 {    transform : rotateZ(294deg)}
.r300 {    transform : rotateZ(300deg)}
.r306 {    transform : rotateZ(306deg)}
.r312 {    transform : rotateZ(312deg)}
.r318 {    transform : rotateZ(318deg)}
.r324 {    transform : rotateZ(324deg)}
.r330 {    transform : rotateZ(330deg)}
.r336 {    transform : rotateZ(336deg)}
.r342 {    transform : rotateZ(342deg)}
.r348 {    transform : rotateZ(348deg)}
.r354 {    transform : rotateZ(354deg)}
.r358 {    transform : rotateZ(360deg)}
</style>


<div class="containerX">
        <div class="frame">
        <div class="secHand"></div>
        
        <div class="minHand">
            <div class="miniCut"></div>
            </div>
            
        <div class="hourHand">
            <div class="hourCut"></div>
            </div>
            
<div class="innerFrame"></div> 
<div class="smallFrame"></div>          
<div class="knob"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r0 indicators"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r6"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r12"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r18"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r24"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r30 indicators"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r36"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r42"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r48"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r54"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r60 indicators"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r66"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r72"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r78"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r84"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r90 indicators"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r96"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r102"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r108"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r114"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r120 indicators"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r126"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r132"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r138"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r144"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r150 indicators"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r156"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r162"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r168"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r174"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r180 indicators"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r186"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r192"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r198"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r204"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r210 indicators"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r216"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r222"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r228"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r234"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r240 indicators"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r246"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r252"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r258"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r264"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r270 indicators"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r276"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r282"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r288"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r294"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r300 indicators"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r306"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r312"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r318"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r324"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r330 indicators"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r336"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r342"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r348"></div>
        <div class="calibrate r354"></div>


    </div>
</div>
```

---

### How it works

This solution updates style sheet rules for keyframe animation values. It does not investigate placing clock hand element in separate containers which are themselves rotated.

#### Style sheet usage.

- Style tags in HTML create an [HTMLStyleElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLStyleElement) in the DOM. The element's content provides CSS source **text**.
- Link tags with a 'rel="stylesheet" attribute create an [HTMLinkElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLLinkElement) in the DOM. The element's source provides CSS  source **text**.
- CSS source text provided by a STYLE or LINK element is parsed to generate a [CSSStyleSheet](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet) object. Each style sheet **object**  generated is added to the `document.styleSheets` array.
- Each style sheet object has an `ownerNode` property which refers to the DOM HTMLElement used to create it.
- Each style sheet object contains an array-like list of rule objects in its `cssRules` property.
- The type of each rule object is held in its [type property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSRule#Type_constants). The `type` value for an `@keyframes` at-rule is 7.
- `@keyframes` rules themselves have a `CSSRules` property containing a list of [keyFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSKeyframeRule) rule objects.
- `keyFrame` rules have properties `keyText` (not used) and `style`. The style object value is read-only but not frozen - its properties can be updated.

#### Simplifications.

The `findSheetById` method uses the `id` value of the HTML element which generated the style sheet object, to find the object in the `document.styleSheets` array. It is possible to find the style sheet starting from the owner node, but documentation lacks detail. Another alternative is to refer to the style sheet by hard coding its `document.styleSheets` index into the program.

The `@keyframes` rules for hours, minutes and seconds are searched for among top level style sheet rules. Nesting them within `@media` rules would introduce further complications.

The `keyFrame` rules are assumed to occur in pairs and indexed by subscripts 0 and 1. Their `keyText` values ("0%" and "100%") are not checked.

The `setClock` function defaults the millisecond argument to zero if not supplied (as in the example). In reality I would suggest supplying the millisecond time value for improved clock accuracy.

#### Online experimentation.

For online testing you could try returning `document.styleSheets[0]` from `findSheetById`, or put a style element complete with id in the HTML box of the online tool.

Comment: this has been very useful, and I could just copy and paste the code and keep moving but I really need to understand the functions in details, the meaning of those properties and how they work. And for get time, you didn't get msec this time, and why did you set it to 0? cos obviously || will make it go for 0.

Comment: finding the degrees also changed from dividing the sec and min by 60 to multiply by 360 and dividing the hour by 12 to multiply by 360 to getting the remainders of sec and min by 60 to multiply by 6 and the reminder of hour by 12 to multiply by 30. I understood the first method but I don't understand this new one.

Comment: now some kinda confusion has set in, I am editing this at codepen and it seems as though adding an id to the css is impossible.

Comment: That appears to be a limitation of  both code pen and  SO code snippets for the sake of simplicity. The workaround I used was to put the CSS  between style tags at the start of HTML content, not in the CSS section. If you open the test code you can see the CSS tags are at the beginning of the HTML box rather than in a separate CSS container. If all else fails you could test using a local HTML file :)

Comment: I used cancellation the second time around: `/60 * 360`  is the same as multiplying by 6, and `/12 * 360` as multiplying by 30. I didn't  mention it  but I agree the uncancelled operations are _clearer_. I'll try and add "how it works" later today - it was interesting to discover.

Comment: See updated answer for response to previous comments.

Comment: this feels great, I will take my time to go through it.