# Creating two different styles for two different blinking class in css

Tags: html, css

I want to make two different styles for two blinking class using html and css. My sample code is as follows:

```css
.blinking{
    animation:blinkingText 0.8s infinite;
}
.blinking2{
    animation:blinkingText 0.8s infinite;
}
@keyframes blinkingText{
    0%{ color: #000;    }
    49%{    color: red; }
    50%{    color: red; }
    99%{    color: red; }
    100%{   color: #000;    }
}
```

```html
<span class="blinking">Am I blinking?</span><br/>
<span class="blinking2">Am I blinking?</span>
```

I want to make blinking2 class yellow colored. is there any way to achiive this?

Comment: Why don't you make another **keyframes** with yellow color?

Comment: You might be looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18481550/how-to-dynamically-create-keyframe-css-animations this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use another `keyframe` for the other blinkingText(yellow).

Try this:

```css
.blinking{
    animation:blinkingText 0.8s infinite;
}
.blinking2{
    animation:blinkingText2 0.8s infinite;
}
@keyframes blinkingText{
    0%{ color: #000;    }
    49%{    color: red; }
    50%{    color: red; }
    99%{    color: red; }
    100%{   color: #000;    }
}
@keyframes blinkingText2{
    0%{ color: #000;    }
    49%{    color: yellow; }
    50%{    color: yellow; }
    99%{    color: yellow; }
    100%{   color: #000;    }
}
```

```html
<span class="blinking">Am I blinking?</span><br/>
<span class="blinking2">Am I blinking?</span>
```

Comment: @user10903858 it is, look carefully or just change the color.

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS variables and you will only need one keyframe:

```css
.blinking{
    animation:blinkingText 1s infinite;
}
.yellow{
    --c:yellow;
}
@keyframes blinkingText{
    0%{ color: #000;    }
    49%{    color: var(--c,lightblue); }
    50%{    color: var(--c,lightblue); }
    99%{    color: var(--c,lightblue); }
    100%{   color: #000;    }
}
```

```html
<span class="blinking">Am I blinking?</span><br>
<span class="blinking yellow">Am I blinking?</span><br>
<span class="blinking" style="--c:lightgreen">Am I blinking?</span>
```