# How do I run this piece for css code through javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, stylesheet

Thanks for taking out the time to look into this and any help in this regard is appreciated.

I have the following piece of code.

```
.middle_n.expand.remove
{
 animation: contractm 0.3s forwards;
 transform-origin: 0 75px;
 height:200%;
 animation-delay: 1.3s;
}

@keyframes contractm 
{
 0%{}
 100%{transform:translate(147.8%,100%) rotate(-16.75deg);}
}
```

I wish to pass a dynamic value to rotate in contractm through javascript. How do I do that. Can multi step animation run through javascript?

Thanks again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to dynamically create '@-Keyframe' CSS animations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18481550/how-to-dynamically-create-keyframe-css-animations)

Comment: Try using CSS variables dynamically set with JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, if you want to control your animation rather than just let it animate, my recommendation is that you can use js to control the style of your element. Because `animation` is to complete a series of animation.

And there is a really powerful css called css variable, you can take more details on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties.

```js
const rotate=document.getElementById("rotate")
let r=0
rotate.addEventListener("click",()=>{
  r += 10
  rotate.style.setProperty("--rotate", r+"deg");
})
```

```css
#rotate{
  --rotate:0deg;
  background:pink;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  transform:rotate(var(--rotate));
  transition:transform 1s;
}
```

```html
<p>click the square and then it will rotate.</p>
<div id="rotate"></div>
```

Of course, if you want a series of animations, you can check it on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation. It's easy to set steps in animation.