# CSS rolling ball animation position

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

**General info**
I'm working on a Bingo game. Currently I'm trying to create a CSS rolling ball animation. The idea is to simulate a ball dropping from the wheel and making it roll from right to left.

**The problem**
The animation is working fine. But the "drop in" position is relative to the div. As a consequence of this, this position keeps moving right 75 pixels on each new ball dropping in.

**Solutions I've tried**
- Give the balls an absolute position. This solves the issue, but each ball will cover the previous balls due to the keyframe ending at `left: 0%`. This is not desirable.
- Lookup Javascript solutions to see if I can somehow change the keyframe to end with +75px on the previous ball. Unfortunately it seems impossible to manipulate animations this way, or I was unable to find a way to do it.

So now I'm hoping someone is able to help me find a solution to this problem.

Edit: I didn't tag jQuery because it's not used here, but solutions using jQuery are perfectly fine.

**MCVE**

```js
const timer = setInterval(rollBall, 2000);
var ballNumber = 1;

function rollBall(){
 if(document.getElementById('ball-'+(ballNumber-1))){
   document.getElementById('ball-'+(ballNumber-1)).classList.remove('ball-animation');
  }
 let html = '<div id="ball-'+ballNumber+'" class="ball ball-animation">';
  html += '<p class="ball-number">';
  html += ballNumber;
  html += '</p></div>';
  
  document.getElementById('balls').innerHTML += html;
  
  ballNumber++;
  
  if(ballNumber > 10) {
   clearInterval(timer);
    document.getElementById('ball-'+(ballNumber-1)).classList.remove('ball-animation');
  }
}
```

```css
.ball {
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 width: 75px;
 height: 75px;
 background: red;
 border-radius: 50%;
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(25px 25px, circle, red, #000);
 background: -moz-radial-gradient(25px 25px, circle, red, #000);
 background: radial-gradient(25px 25px, circle, red, #000);
 /*position: absolute;*/
 float: left;
}

.ball-number {
 top: -34px;
 left: 25px;
 font-size: 45px;
 color: #fff;
 position: absolute;
}

.ball-animation {
 -webkit-animation: spin 1750ms linear infinite, moveRightToLeft 2s linear infinite;
 -moz-animation: spin 1750ms linear infinite, moveRightToLeft 2s linear infinite;
 -ms-animation: spin 1750ms linear infinite, moveRightToLeft 2s linear infinite;
 animation: spin 1750ms linear infinite, moveRightToLeft 2s linear;

 -webkit-transition: all 1.75s ease;
 transition: all 1.75s ease;
}

@keyframes spin {
 from { transform: rotate(360deg); }
 to { transform: rotate(0deg); }
}

@keyframes moveRightToLeft {
 0% { top: -50px; left: 200px; }
 10% { top: -40px; left: 180px; }
 20% { top: -25px; left: 150px; }
 30% { top: 0px; left: 100px; }
 100% { left: 0%; }
}
```

```html
<div id="balls"></div>
```

Comment: Assuming you don't want to hand-code the keyframes for each ball, you could [use JS to create/modify keyframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18481550/how-to-dynamically-create-keyframe-css-animations). Also see [this csstricks.com link](https://css-tricks.com/controlling-css-animations-transitions-javascript/).

Comment: Off-topic: I like how the comment on the accepted answer (of the thread @kmoser linked) is relevant to this post.

Comment: @kmoser Thanks. The csstricks link looks promising. Using the `animationend` DOM event might give me a doorway to manipulate values somehow. I'd still have to figure out how, but it could be the point into the right direction I needed.

Comment: wouldn't that not work anyways, because some balls should roll to the right?  otherwise it seems like percentage or calc and variables could make something workable

Comment: @user120242 No it wouldn't work. I already thought about it and it'll cause all sorts of issues. But I've taken another look at the answer in the post kmoser commented and it seems this [jQuery Keyframes](https://github.com/Keyframes/jQuery.Keyframes) plugin is very promising. I think it would allow me to just generate new keyframes for each new ball. That gives me full control over everything I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a CSS only solution, using an intermediate div, *zone* to handle the ball movement .

Since this elements have varying sizes, you can set the keyframes on them to work in percentages, and adjust for a different ending point, while keeping the same origin point.

```css
.container {
    width: 600px;
    height: 350px;
    border: solid 1px red;
    position: relative;
}

.zone {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 40px;
    left: 40px;
    border: solid 1px green;
    animation: move 3s linear infinite;
}

.zone:nth-child(2) {
    left: calc(40px * 2);
}

.zone:nth-child(3) {
    left: calc(40px * 3);
}
.zone:nth-child(4) {
    left: calc(40px * 4);
}

.ball {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
    right: 0px;
    position: absolute;
}

@keyframes move {
    from {transform: translate(0px, 0px);}
    50% {transform: translate(-100px, 100%);}
    to {transform: translate(-100%, 100%);}
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="zone">
    <div class="ball">1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="zone">
    <div class="ball">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="zone">
    <div class="ball">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="zone">
    <div class="ball">4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's definitely interesting, but as you can see in your own answer, the balls don't follow the same path. That's why I used pixels instead of percentages. It's a bingo game. In the end result, the balls look like they come down out of a wheel and roll across a track. It would be quite weird if each new ball starts hovering in the air further away from the track

Comment: In my first answer, the balls were starting at the same position, it was later when the followed different paths. Any way, I have changed the intermediate step, so that they follow the same path when descending. You can adapt it to whatever you want.

Comment: Ye, definitely a lot better! Thanks a lot for all your work this. I really appreciate it!

Comment: Happy that it helped !