# How to define CSS animation entirely from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wish to apply CSS animation to HTML items generated entirely from a JavaScript function. My code involves defining each part of the animation via customizable settings and functions which is why this is necessary. I have no problem defining the animation itself by doing the following in JS:

```
element.style.animation = "sprite_anim 1.0s steps(4) infinite"
```

The problem is the keyframes: They normally need to be a static definition in a CSS file.

```
@keyframes sprite_anim {
    from {
        background-position: 0px 0px;
    }
    to {
        background-position: -128px 0px;
    }
}
```

In this case I want the code to dynamically define those 4 offset values too; They'll be set once per image so it's okay to generate a one-time animation for each combination I'll be using, but the values themselves are computed via script. What is the least intrusive and most browser compatible and shortest way to define my keyframes from the code?

Comment: Have you considered using the Animate API? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/animate, you define the keyframes and the animation parameters using that directly, not with styles

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18481550/how-to-dynamically-create-keyframe-css-animations

Comment: If you are open to use a library , I really like the way gsap works. : https://greensock.com/docs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I can't reply to comments or mark them as a solution: arieljuod provided exactly the answer I needed above. What I was looking for is the element.animate() function which does the same thing as CSS animation but fully from JS as desired.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/animate

Answer (score 1):

If you have just one set of keyframes in your style sheet defined like this:

```
@keyframes sprite_anim {
    from {
        background-position: var(--fromx) var(--fromy);
    }
    to {
        background-position: var(--tox) var(--toy);
    }
}
```

You can for each image in JS set these variables using `element.style.setProperty("--tox", valueforx)` etc.

Comment: That's a good approach to keep in mind too, can be very useful in some cases! For my use case here element.animate() does exactly what I needed so far.